# What are some of the strategy to handle unhandled exception in asp.net mvc applications?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, exception

I would like to know some of the strategy/practice you deal with to handle unhandled exceptions in ASP.NET MVC.

In short I want to avoid the yellow screen whenever any error happens and show a error consistent error message to the visitor.

I mean do you write a controller for this which shows the appropriate error page or you go some other way like writing an httpmodule and trapping the error at a global level.

Any inputs in this direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the HandleError attribute is the way to go. Here is a small sample which I use to handle Ajax calls from JQuery, ExtJs, and others.

On your controller

```
public class DataController : Controller
{    
    [HandleError(ExceptionType = typeof(ArgumentException), View = "ErrorAjax")]
    public void Foo(string x, string y)
    {    
        if (String.IsNullorEmpty(x))
            throw new ArgumentException("String cannot be empty!");

            // Call your layers or whatever here
            AnotherCall();
    }
}
```

Then on your view (ErrorAjax). Notice it's strongly typed (HandleErrorInfo)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<HandleErrorInfo>" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Sorry Dude!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <!-- be creative here-->
        Sorry, an error occurred while processing your request.
        Action = <%= ViewData.Model.ActionName %>
        Controller = <%= ViewData.Model.ControllerName %>
        Message = <%= ViewData.Model.Exception.Message %>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

A couple of gotchas

1. Check your web.config and make sure customErrors mode="On"
2. For starters, create the View under the Shared folder

Comment: 3. also make sure your error page doesn't return any errors. For one must use HandlerErrorInfo as its model - as shown above, but there are of course other possible sources for errors.

Comment: Another slight hint: Make sure to HtmlEncode your Message, or if you're on .net 4 (which wasn't available at the time of the answer), use <%: instead of <%=

Answer (score 4):

Try the [HandleError attribute](http://www.pnpguidance.net/post/ASPNETMVCFrameworkPreview4HandleErrorAuthorizeOutputCacheActionFilterAttributes.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

Don't use the exception handling article that you linked to. It's an old article where they didn't have the HandleError attribute added in the framework. Use the [HandleError attribute](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/07/14/asp-net-mvc-preview-4-release-part-1.aspx). It was added in preview 4.